# How to use Space in a simple grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4, ebnf

I'm beginner at both antlr and ebnf.

I have the following grammar expressed in antlr4:

```
grammar RecordGrammar;

Record: 'record';
EndRecord: 'endrecord';

Track: 'track';
EndTrack: 'endtrack';

Length: 'length';

Name: [a-zA-Z]+;
Number: [0-9]+;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+;

records: (record)+ EOF;

record: Record WS Name WS
            tracks WS?
        EndRecord WS?;

tracks: track WS? (track WS)*;

track: Track WS
          length
       EndTrack WS?;

length: Length WS Number WS?;
```

When I use the grammar above (with antlr) on the this text:

```
record help
    track
     length 2
    endtrack
    track
       length 4
    endtrack
    track
       length 42
    endtrack
endrecord
```

...it works nice and dandy.

But I want to extend the 'Name' rule in the EBNF to also accept Space.

So I want the grammar to accept this text file also:

```
record help me
    track
     length 2
    endtrack
    track
       length 4
    endtrack
    track
       length 42
    endtrack
endrecord
```

Observe the text "help me" on the right side of the record tag.

How can I achieve this in the grammar? Since Space is a natural delimiter, I need some kind special treatment for that in my rules. Thanks for all help I can get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `name` parser rule that matches multiple `Name` tokens:

```
name : Name (WS+ Name)*;
```

But since you're not really doing anything with spaces, mind as well discard them during tokenisation by adding `-> skip` to it and then removing all `WS` from your parser rules:

```
grammar RecordGrammar;

records     : record+ EOF;
record      : Record name tracks EndRecord;
tracks      : track+;
track       : Track length EndTrack;
length      : Length Number;
name        : Name+;

Record      : 'record';
EndRecord   : 'endrecord';
Track       : 'track';
EndTrack    : 'endtrack';
Length      : 'length';
Name        : [a-zA-Z]+;
Number      : [0-9]+;
WS          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

which will result in the following parse tree:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should start by deciding how you determine where the name actually ends. In the initial grammar, it's easy - it's a single word so it ends at a whitespace character. In Bart's answer, it's every word between the words 'record' and 'track' <sup>*</sup>. But is that your case, or can the name actually contain the word 'track'?

You might want to also consider following options:

- Terminating the name at the end of the line (in that case the whitespace becomes significant, and you need to allow that word in name, making it a *non-reserved keyword*).
- Enclosing a multi-word name in quotes (`"`) or apostrophes (`'`) - in that case whitespace is not significant and can  be skipped as per Bart's answer.

*) It's more complicated than that actually - but that is a basic idea of how it looks for the end of the record name.

Comment: It will a problem when the name contains the word 'track'. I understand that the parser will be confused. Adding "track" as a reserved keyword might be an alternative, but I can't allow quotes or apostrophes. I'm grateful for your and Bart's help in this area. Thanks again!